# Why is Node.js named Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm just curious why Node.js was named that. I searched their site and their FAQ and there was nothing that helped me understand why it was named Node.js.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The official name is actually `Node`. Originally it was designed for use as a web application, but the author realized it could be used for more general purposes and renamed it to node.

Here is [a quote from the author](http://bostinno.streetwise.co/2011/01/31/node-js-interview-4-questions-with-creator-ryan-dahl/) that may help explain the name:

> Node is a single-threaded, single-process system which enforces shared-nothing design with OS process boundaries. It has rather good libraries for networking. I believe this to be a basis for designing very large distributed programs. The “nodes” need to be organized: given a communication protocol, told how to connect to each other.  In the next couple months we are working on libraries for Node that allow these networks.

Comment: he talks about this in the excellent [Intro to Node JS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo_B4LTHi3I) very briefly near the end.

Answer (score 19):

Check out [this](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/03/01/the_rise_and_rise_of_node_dot_js/) article. From [page 4](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/03/01/the_rise_and_rise_of_node_dot_js/page4.html):

> Originally, Dahl called his project
>   web.js. It was merely a webserver, an
>   alternative to Apache and other
>   "blocking" servers. But the project
>   soon grew beyond his initial webserver
>   library, expanding into a framework
>   that could be used to build, well,
>   almost anything. So he rechristened it
>   node.js.

Answer (score 10):

On wiki it says, that the project is called node, but to make sure it does not get mixed up with other "node", the .js was added to it