# What does node really mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, definition

I always see the word `node`. As far as I know node means a connecting point... So what do `child nodes` really mean and what do they do? How are they related to `node.js`?

Sorry for asking this stupid question. I am really new to AJAX & building a web application.

Comment: What's the context ? One common use of the word node is to refer to the elements in a tree, eg the DOM tree

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5622171/514749.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For javascript, any HTML DOM element is a node.

```
<div>
    <span></span>
    <form>   .... </form>
</div>
```

For example, in the HTML snippet above, `span` and `form` are **child nodes** of `div`.

**Node.js** is just the name of a library. It was named **Node.js** for **other different**  reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Node as in node in a graph (or DOM tree in this case). It's more or less a coincidence Node.js happens to be named the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not elaborating, but I think you should start by reading about HTML DOM & JS.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_node.asp

Shortly, an XML page (thus including HTML) is build on what is called a Document Object Model, in which every element, attribute, comment, etc. are represented as a node. Some node can contain sub-nodes which are called children. These are the basics for all xml/html document communications and manipulations.

Comment: If one is about to start learning about HTML, DOM, JS or anything related, w3schools is **not** a source they should be using. Plenty of good other sources listed here http://w3fools.com/#what-should-be-done

Comment: I linked to where I learned from, but thanks a lot for the alternatives, I will definitely check them out.